# How can I automatically populate user name and update time when a cell is updated?

Tags: vba, excel

Say I have a sheet with 4 columns as the following:

```
value1 | value2 | updated by | update time
abc    |        | Employee1  | 18/12/2014 18:13
       | xyz    | Employee2  | 18/12/2014 18:13
```

I want the columns "updated by" and "update time" to be automatically updated if any of the cells in Value1 or Value2 has been updated.

The column updated by takes the name of the user that made the change, it can be the Windows user name or Excel username.

The column update time takes the time when any of the cells value1 or value2 has been updated.

I have no VBA knowledge; is there any way how to achieve this result? I have been searching online, I found out how to populate the update time column via a VBA procedure but the result is not exactly what is expected, and couldn't find how to pouplate the Updated By column.

The VBA code I found online to populate the time is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A100")) Is Nothing Then 
        Target(1, 4) = Now 
        Target(1, 4).EntireColumn.AutoFit 
    End If 
End Sub
```

source: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24219

Comment: However you address your problem (some good suggestion below) you should also remember that `Target` is not always a single-cell range, so you should account for that if you want your code to be robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the possible VBA solution to your problem:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 2 Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If (ThisRow = 1) Then Exit Sub
        ' time stamp corresponding to cell's last update
        Range("D" & ThisRow).Value = Now
        ' Windows level UserName | Application level UserName
        Range("C" & ThisRow).Value = Environ("username") & "|" & Application.UserName
        Range("C:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If
End Sub
```

In order to protect Header Row from changes you can add code snippet shown below:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
                 ThisRow = Target.Row
                 'protect Header row from any changes
                 If (ThisRow = 1) Then
                        Application.EnableEvents = False
                        Application.Undo
                        Application.EnableEvents = True
                        MsgBox "Header Row is Protected."
                        Exit Sub
                 End If
                 If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 2 Then
                        ' time stamp corresponding to cell's last update
                        Range("D" & ThisRow).Value = Now
                        ' Windows level UserName | Application level UserName
                        Range("C" & ThisRow).Value = Environ("username") & "|" & Application.UserName
                    Range("C:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
                 End If
End Sub
```

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: If the columns Updated By and Updated Time are protected, it would throw an error when the user makes some change to the values cells, is it possible to keep the two columns protected or they should be unprotected?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. It implies that the Columns of interest and Worksheet are unprotected. If you have more questions on Excel data protection, please post it separately. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

For the windows user name you could use

```
ActiveCell.Value = Environ("username")
```

What didn't work out for the time stamp?

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:B")) Is Nothing Then

    Cells(Target.Row, 3) = Now                   'Current time
    Cells(Target.Row, 4) = Application.UserName  'Excel User Name
    Cells(Target.Row, 5) = Environ("UserName")   'Windows User Name

    Range("C:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End If
```

End Sub